# How can I keep the user from interrupting the event that's currently running?

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that changes the background color of the header every time a nav link is clicked. I have a setTimeout function within that function that holds that color for 2s before changing it back to the background image. The bug I have is that I can just keep clicking a nav button and keep changing the color which messes up the timing. Its important that that color stays the same for 2s before changing back to an image. Then after the timeout has ran the user can change the color again. I've tried using a boolen to check if there already is a color but I can't get it to work.

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links .link');
const linksArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.links div'));
const header = document.querySelector('header');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const hamMenu = document.querySelector('.ham-menu');

for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
 navLinks[i].addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}

for (var i = 0; i < linksArray.length; i++) {
 linksArray[i].addEventListener('click', shuffle);
}

function changeColor() {
 let hexArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
 let hexColor = '#';

 for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*hexArray.length);
  hexColor += hexArray[random];
 }

 if(!hasColor) {
  header.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
  header.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
 }

 setTimeout(function() {
  header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/canada.jpeg)';
 }, 2000);
}

function shuffle() { //  Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
  for (let i = linksArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); 
    [linksArray[i].innerHTML, linksArray[j].innerHTML] = [linksArray[j].innerHTML, linksArray[i].innerHTML]; 
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
 const address = document.querySelector('.address').value;
 const city = document.querySelector('.city').value;
 const dialog = document.querySelector('.dialog-wrap');
 const close = document.querySelector('.close');

 dialog.style.display = 'block';
 document.querySelector('.dialog-name').innerHTML = name;
 document.querySelector('.dialog-address').innerHTML = address;
 document.querySelector('.dialog-city').innerHTML = city;
 close.onclick = () => {
  dialog.style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
 }
 
})

hamMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const nav = document.querySelector('nav');
 nav.classList.toggle('ham-open');
})
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Verdana';
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #63889b;
}

/** {
 outline: 1px solid red;
}*/

/*------NAV-----*/

nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 padding: 25px 0;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px rgb(99, 99, 99, 0.5);
}

.brand, .nav-links {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.brand {
 margin-left: 6%;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5;
}

.logo {
 max-width: 70px;
 max-height: 45px;
 margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-links {
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 6%;
}

.nav-links .link {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-right: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

.nav-links .link:hover {
 color: #014263;
}

.ham-menu {
 display: none;
}

/*-----HEADER-----*/

header {
 background-image: url(img/canada.jpeg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 80vh;
 margin-top: 92px;
}

.header-info {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 padding: 35px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 4%;
}

header p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header p:first-child {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}


/*-----MAIN-----*/

main {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.col {
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 padding: 50px 0 40px 0;
}

.col p {
 width: 65%;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.col img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.col-3 img {
 width: 280px;
 height: 155px;
}

.col-3 img, .col-3 h3, .col-3 p {
 position: relative;
 top: -8px;
}

.col-2 img, .col-2 h3, .col-2 p {
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
}

.col-1 {
 margin-left: 7%;
}

.col-3 {
 margin-right: 7%;
}

h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

/*------FOOTER-----*/

footer {
 font-family: 'Helvetica';
 background-color: #63889b;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 30px 100px 30px 100px;
}

.internal-links h4 {
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 color: #fff;
}

.links div {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 margin:2px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}


.form-wrap {
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

form {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 100%;
}

input {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}

label {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 padding: 3px 0;
}

button {
 margin-top: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 width: 50%;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 background-color: #4678c9;
 align-self: flex-end;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 4px 30px;
}

.dialog-wrap {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

dialog {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 500px;
 border: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

dialog div {
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 10px 0;
 outline: 1px solid #63889b;
}

dialog div:first-child {
 margin-top: 0px;
}

dialog .label {
 background-color: #63889b;
 padding: 7px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

dialog .info {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 5px;
 color: #000;
}

dialog button {
 border: none;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 7px;
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
}

dialog button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all .3s ease;
 background-color: #0675ad;
}

dialog div:last-child {
 outline: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {

 /*-----HEADER-----*/

 .header-info {
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 width: 392px;
 margin-left: 7%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {

 /*-----HEADER-----*/

 header {
  height: 70vh;
 }

 /*-----MAIN-----*/

 .col p, .links {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

 /*-----NAV-----*/

 nav {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .brand {
     margin-left: 3%;
 }

 .nav-links {
     margin-right: 3%;
 }

 /*-----HEADER-----*/

 .header-info {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: 363px;
 }

 /*-----MAIN-----*/

 .col-1 img {
  width: 270px;
  height: 132px;
 }

 .col-2 img {
  width: 280px;
  height: 107px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
 }

 .col p, .links div, label {
  font-size: 1rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

 /*-----MAIN-----*/

 .col p {
  width: 85%;
 }

 .col-1 img {
  width: 230px;
     height: 112px; 
 }

 .col-2 img {
  width: 190px;
     height: 82px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
  width: 210px;
     height: 120px;
 }

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 button {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

 dialog div {
     font-size: 1.2rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {

 /*-----NAV-----*/

 nav {
     font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 /*-----HEADER-----*/

 .header-info {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 308px
 }


 header {
  height: 60vh;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

    input {
     font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 footer {
  padding: 30px 70px 30px 70px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

 /*-----MAIN-----*/

 main {
  padding: 0 10px;
 }

 .col-1 img {
     width: 190px;
     height: 92px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
     width: 170px;
     height: 100px;
 }

 .col-2 {
  padding-top: 30px;
 }

 .col {
      margin: 0 10px;
 }
 
 .col p {
  width: 100%;
 }

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 footer {
  margin-top: -20px;
 }

 button {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 765px) {

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 .col p, .links, label {
     font-size: 0.9rem;
 }

 dialog {
  width: 400px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 728px) {

 /*-----NAV-----*/

 nav {
     font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 .internal-links h4 {
     font-size: 1.3rem; 
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

 /*-----MAIN-----*/

 .col-1 img {
     width: 160px;
     height: 80px;
 }

 .col-2 img {
     width: 170px;
     height: 70px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
     width: 140px;
     height: 87px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

 /*-----HEADER-----*/

    .comp-name {
     position: relative;
     right: 15px;
    }

    .nav-links .link {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 16px;
    }

 /*-----MAIN-----*/

 main {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .col-1 img {
     width: 230px;
     height: 112px;
 }

 .col-2 img, .col-2 h3, .col-2 p {
     position: static;
 }

 .col-2 img {
     width: 280px;
     height: 119px;
 }

 .col-3 img {
     width: 210px;
     height: 120px;
 }

 .col {
  padding: 30px 0 20px 0;
 }

 .col p {
     width: 90%;
 }

 /*------FOOTER-----*/

 button {
     font-size: 1rem;
    }

 footer {
  margin-top: 0;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {

 /*------NAV-----*/

 nav {
  padding: 15px 0;
 }

 .logo {
  max-width: 60px;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .nav-links {
  display: none;
 }

 .b1, .b2, .b3 {
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #4678c9;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease;
 }

 .ham-open .nav-links {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     margin: 0;
     padding: 100px 0;
 }

 .ham-open .nav-links .link {
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .ham-open .comp-name {
  color: #fff;
 }

 .ham-open .b1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, 8px);
 }

 .ham-open .b2 {
     opacity: 0;
 }

 .ham-open .b3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(9px, -9px);;
 }

 /*-----HEADER-----*/

 header {
  margin-top: 66px;
 }

 .header-info {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
 }

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 footer {
     padding: 30px 40px 30px; 
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 .internal-links h4 {
     font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

 .links div, label {
     font-size: 15px;
 }

 button {
     margin-top: 8px;
 }

 footer {
     padding: 20px 30px 20px;
 }

 dialog {
     width: 340px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {

 /*-----FOOTER-----*/

 footer {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .internal-links {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .links {
  text-align: center;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 
 /*-----HEADER-----*/

 .header-info {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 262px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Chapman Automotive Skills Assessment</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <div class="brand">
  <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
  <div class="comp-name">CHAPMAN</div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-links">
   <div class="link">Home</div>
   <div class="link">Sales</div>
   <div class="link">Blog</div>
   <div class="link">Login</div>
  </div>

  <div class="ham-menu">
   <div class="b1"></div>
   <div class="b2"></div>
   <div class="b3"></div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <header>
  <div class="header-info">
   <p>We are a company that does stuff.</p>
   <p>Car and web stuff.</p>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="col col-1">
   <img src="img/car1.jpg" alt="car1">

   <h3>Some Header</h3>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo tempore quia enim quod, perferendis illum quae id, natus dolores temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, rem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-2">
   <img src="img/car2.jpg" alt="car2">

   <h3>More Stuff</h3>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo tempore quia enim quod, perferendis illum quae id, natus dolores temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-3">
   <img src="img/car3.jpg" alt="car3">

   <h3>Last Column</h3>

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo tempore quia enim quod, perferendis illum quae id, natus dolores temporibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, ipsa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer id="footer">
  <div class="internal-links">
   <h4>Internal Links</h4>

   <div class="links">
    <div>Page One</div>
    <div>Another Page</div>
    <div>Sales Page</div>
    <div>Page Three</div>
    <div>Keep Going</div>
    <div>Last One</div>
    <div>Just Kidding</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-wrap">
   <form>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="name" required>
    <label for="Name">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="address" required>
    <label for="Name">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="city" required>

    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit Form</button>
   </form>

   <div class="dialog-wrap">
    <dialog>
     <div><span class="label">Name:</span><span class="dialog-name info"></span></div>
     <div><span class="label">Address:</span><span class="dialog-address info"></span></div>
     <div><span class="label">City:</span><span class="dialog-city info"></span></div>
     <div><button class="close">Close</button></div>
    </dialog>
   </div>
 </footer>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 900 lines of code, did you call that a Minimal, Reproducible Example of your problem ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have a GOB of code here.
How about:
1) Have a global variable

```
var switch1 = 0;
```

2) Your first statements in your nav code:

```
if (switch1 == 1) return; 
switch1 = 1;
```

3) Your setTimeout would be:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/canada.jpeg)';
    switch1 = 0;
  }, 2000);
```

This is such a simplistic approach, I'm almost ashamed to post it.